# Cannot connect to postgres docker container on remote server with .net core application. But can connect with pg admin

Tags: .net, postgresql, docker, entity-framework, containers

**Issue**

I want to connect to a Postgres image I have on a remote server with my .NET Core application.

I created a Postgres image on a digital ocean server and I am trying to connect to it with my .NET Core application. However I am getting the following error when I run `update-database` trying to apply my migrations:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The handle is invalid.)

On the server side, when I check the logs of the Docker container, I get

```
2024-01-04 15:08:09.089 UTC [122] LOG: invalid length of startup packet
```

This is my connection string:

```
Server=<server-IP-address>,5432;Database=<dbname>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=postgres; Password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=30;
```

I don't understand why I can't connect to the server with .NET Core. I know my credentials are correct and my firewall on the server are configured correctly as I can access and create tables in the database with pgadmin, and with my terminal. It only doesn't work with the .NET Core application and SQL Server Management Studio.

I have tried various configurations of `Encrypt=False/True;TrustServerCertificate=True/False` as many of the other stackoverflow questions have suggested and also tried to modify the `pg_hba.config` file on the server as this post suggest: [How to create a connection from .NET Service to Remote PostgreSQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54630604/how-to-create-a-connection-from-net-service-to-remote-postgresql-server)

I have also tried enabling TSL 1.2, running netsh Winsock reset, ipconfig \flushdns, as many have suggested but nothing works and the error message is still the same

Answer (score 0):

Are you running both the .NET application and pgadmin from localhost?
Have you tried printing the connectionstring from runtime to make sure the the variables are configured correctly?

Comment: Yes they're both running from localhost! but only the pgadmin is able to connect to the remote server. The connection string on .NET should be correct and the server is receiving the connection but throws the error: 

"2024-01-04 15:08:09.089 UTC [122] LOG: invalid length of startup packet"

Im not sure what this means , but im sure my password is correct as its exactly what i used when connecting with pgadmin